# Cherry-pick commits from different branches into the master branch

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Can we cherry-pick commits from two different branches into a third branch? For suppose I have two branches(develop and master). I created two branches A and B from develop and merged them into the develop branch.

I want to cherry-pick the changes I merged into develop branch to the master branch.

Can we do that? If so, how?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't merge `develop` into the `master` branch?  You may not even need cherry pick here.

Comment: Cherry-pick one commit at a time. It doesn't matter how many branches there are.

Comment: Cherry-pick picks commits, it doesn't really need a branch membership of any kind.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen It is just that I maintain both branches seperately. There are extra changes on develop I dont want on the master branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply have to checkout master
`git checkout master`

and then for each commit you want to cherry-pick from `develop` (or from `a` or from `b`)

`git cherry-pick -x <SHA of commit>` or if you want you can use a range where `A` is the oldest to grab and `B` is newest and want `A`, `B`, and everything in between: `git cherry-pick -x A..B`

that said as others have mentioned it might make more sense to simply merge `develop` into `master` unless there are other items on `develop` that can't be merged yet. If you can't things do get more complicated. In that case I would consider rebasing `A` and `B` on top of master first using `rebase --onto` you'll need some more syntax you can find on the web for that, merging them into master, and then merging master into develop to unify things. but if you want to cherry pick, go ahead.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This helped and like all suggestions, cherry-picking each commit into master worked as I didnt want to merge develop and master branches.

Comment: Careful: cherry picking merge commits might be non trivial.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Can I know in why?

Comment: A merge commit represents a delta from two parent branches.  You would have to choose which parent's delta you want to cherry pick.